# Expose Style Properties as Global Settings for Users to Change

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a Resource Dictionary which defines a lot of styles for my application. 
As an example: one of the style is for AlternateRowBackground color of a grid in  GridStyles.xaml

```
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AlternateRowBackground" color="Gray" />
```

How can I expose this to the user ? So at run time, if he wants to change this to red/ yellow/ etc.. he can.

1. If and can I expose these properties as the end user? how ?(not worried about the UI, just the mechanics)
2. If not , I guess I will have to create a new style based on existing and copying changing the respective property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For, everybody else who wants to know how this was done. 
here is how I solved this.

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static model:GlobalSettingsModel.Instance},Path=AlternateRowBackground}"/>
```